# How yo query a string with an ObjectID in subquery

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a query problem in mongoDB.

This query executed :

```
db.client_data.find(    
... {       
... client_data_type_id : ObjectId("533bde998a223858e3c8d352"),  "list_attributes.535e70158a22382679a738d3" : "535f5b798a22383f5a59c86f"    
... },    
... {
... _id : 1   
... } )
```

gives me this result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535f5bb78a22383f5a59c870") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535f5bd28a22383f5a59c871") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535f5bda8a22383f5a59c872") }
```

I now want to execute this query :

```
db.client_data.find(
{
      client_data_type_id : ObjectId("533a7d258a22383070aa1092"), 
      "list_attributes.535e27768a22387ca86974cb" : 
      {
$in : [
db.client_data.find(    
{       
client_data_type_id : ObjectId("533bde998a223858e3c8d352"),  "list_attributes.535e70158a22382679a738d3" : "535f5b798a22383f5a59c86f"    
},    
{
_id : 1   
} ) 
]
     }
   },
   {
           _id : 0,
    list_attributes : 1
   }
)
```

If i execute this query with string, it works :

```
db.client_data.find(
   {
        client_data_type_id : ObjectId("533a7d258a22383070aa1092"), 
    "list_attributes.535e27768a22387ca86974cb" : 
    {
$in : [
        "535f5bda8a22383f5a59c872",
        "535f5bd28a22383f5a59c871",
"535f5bb78a22383f5a59c870", 
    ]
            }
   },
   {
           _id : 0,
    list_attributes : 1
   }
)
```

This gives me the right result.
But with the subquery, it doesn't work because the subquery gives me ObjectID and I have to execute query with String.

Do you know how to do this ??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe, you should to find way to convert ObjectId to String.

Comment: How can i convert objectid to string in the result of a subquery to use it inside the query ??

Comment: Could you edit your post to clean up the formatting of the code?  It's very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str(objectid) to turn an ObjectId into it's hexadecimal representation.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html